# Show an image div onclick event

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to show an **image div** on same page when click on a link using **javascript**? How can I achieve this?

Comment: What's an image div? What have you tried? Post your code please and expand your question.

Comment: <a href="#">Click Here</a> this is my link and i want a div open when i click on it. I tried to use javascript but i dont have much idea about it

Answer (score 1):

In Javascript:

```
 <script language="javascript"> 
    function toggle() {
        var ele = document.getElementById("toggleImage");

        if(ele.style.display == "block") {
                ele.style.display = "none";     
        }
        else {
            ele.style.display = "block";        
        }
    } 
    </script>

    <a id="displayText" href="javascript:toggle();">show</a> 
    <img id="toggleImage" style="display: none" src="/abc.jpeg" />
```

Comment: I updated it in javascript.